# Pytorch training loop for pix2code autoencoder model

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm, autoencoder

I am trying to implement the [pix2code Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07962) according to [this blogpost](https://blog.floydhub.com/turning-design-mockups-into-code-with-deep-learning/) using Pytorch instead of Tensorflow. I want to focus only on the HTML version from the post.

In short terms: a pretrained cnn is used to extract a featuremap from the screenshot. Then the feature map is given to an encoder. Another encoder is used to extract features from an given sequence, that is already preprocessed (tokenized and numericalized text). The features extracted by the cnn and rnn will be concatenated and given to an LSTM Decoder, which then generates HTML token by token.

I already build the model and everything else, but now I am stuck at implementing the training loop. Thanks to the tensorflow fit function, which is mysterious to me.

I would really appreciate if somebody out there could give me some hints!! I am wondering about how to init and use the hidden states. If I am missing some important information just let me know and I will provide.

```
class VM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nfeat = 128):
        super(VM, self).__init__()
        # Linear input size of feature map extracted by resnet
        self.fc = nn.Linear(256*14*14, nfeat)
    
    def forward(self, images):
        out = images.reshape(images.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out

    class LM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ntoken, ninp=200, nhidden = 256, nfeat = 128, nlayers=2):
        super(LM, self).__init__()
        self.nlayers = nlayers
        self.nhid = nhidden
        
        self.encoder = nn.Embedding(ntoken, ninp)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(ninp, nhidden, nlayers)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(nhidden, nfeat)
    
    def forward(self, seq, hidden):
        embed = self.encoder(seq)
        out, hidden = self.lstm(embed, hidden)
        out = self.decoder(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out, hidden
    
    def init_hidden(self, bsz):
        weight = next(self.parameters())
        return (weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid), weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid))

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ntoken, ninp, nhidden=512, nlayers=1):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.nlayers = nlayers
        self.nhid = nhidden
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(ninp, nhidden, nlayers)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(nhidden, ntoken)
    
    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return F.log_softmax(out, dim=1), hidden
    
    def init_hidden(self, bsz):
        weight = next(self.parameters())
        return (weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid), weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid))

    class Pix2Code(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ntoken): # , ninp, nhidden=512, nlayers=1
        super(Pix2Code, self).__init__()
        self.vm = VM(nfeat=128)
        self.lm = LM(ntoken=ntoken, ninp=200, nhidden = 256, nfeat = 128, nlayers=2)
        self.decoder = Decoder(ntoken=ntoken, ninp=256)
    
    def forward(self, imgs, seqs, hidden):
        img_feats = vm(imgs)
        seq_feats = lm(seqs)
        features = torch.cat((vm_out, lm_out), 2) 
        return decoder(features), hidden
    
    def init_hidden(self, bsz):
        weight = next(self.parameters())
        return (weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid), weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid))
```